# Could i use ansible playbook(tgz,zip format ) like helm charts?

Tags: ansible

I want to use ansible to manage multi service deployment, each service have many roles. Now I want to package one service as a tgz or zip file(same as helm charts), and use one file to override variables when use ansible execute(like helm install xx.tgz --values values.yml)

I am new to ansible, and have checked ansible-playbook -h, but no find some related information

```sh
Usage: ansible-playbook [options] playbook.yml [playbook2 ...]

Runs Ansible playbooks, executing the defined tasks on the targeted hosts.

Options:
  --ask-vault-pass      ask for vault password
  -C, --check           don't make any changes; instead, try to predict some
                        of the changes that may occur
  -D, --diff            when changing (small) files and templates, show the
                        differences in those files; works great with --check
  -e EXTRA_VARS, --extra-vars=EXTRA_VARS
                        set additional variables as key=value or YAML/JSON, if
                        filename prepend with @
  --flush-cache         clear the fact cache for every host in inventory
  --force-handlers      run handlers even if a task fails
  -f FORKS, --forks=FORKS
                        specify number of parallel processes to use
                        (default=5)
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INVENTORY, --inventory=INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host path or comma separated host
                        list. --inventory-file is deprecated
  -l SUBSET, --limit=SUBSET
                        further limit selected hosts to an additional pattern
  --list-hosts          outputs a list of matching hosts; does not execute
                        anything else
  --list-tags           list all available tags
  --list-tasks          list all tasks that would be executed
  -M MODULE_PATH, --module-path=MODULE_PATH
                        prepend colon-separated path(s) to module library (def
                        ault=~/.ansible/plugins/modules:/usr/share/ansible/plu
                        gins/modules)
  --skip-tags=SKIP_TAGS
                        only run plays and tasks whose tags do not match these
                        values
  --start-at-task=START_AT_TASK
                        start the playbook at the task matching this name
  --step                one-step-at-a-time: confirm each task before running
  --syntax-check        perform a syntax check on the playbook, but do not
                        execute it
  -t TAGS, --tags=TAGS  only run plays and tasks tagged with these values
  --vault-id=VAULT_IDS  the vault identity to use
  --vault-password-file=VAULT_PASSWORD_FILES
                        vault password file
  -v, --verbose         verbose mode (-vvv for more, -vvvv to enable
                        connection debugging)
  --version             show program's version number, config file location,
                        configured module search path, module location,
                        executable location and exit

  Connection Options:
    control as whom and how to connect to hosts

    -k, --ask-pass      ask for connection password
    --private-key=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, --key-file=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
                        use this file to authenticate the connection
    -u REMOTE_USER, --user=REMOTE_USER
                        connect as this user (default=None)
    -c CONNECTION, --connection=CONNECTION
                        connection type to use (default=smart)
    -T TIMEOUT, --timeout=TIMEOUT
                        override the connection timeout in seconds
                        (default=10)
    --ssh-common-args=SSH_COMMON_ARGS
                        specify common arguments to pass to sftp/scp/ssh (e.g.
                        ProxyCommand)
    --sftp-extra-args=SFTP_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to sftp only (e.g. -f,
                        -l)
    --scp-extra-args=SCP_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to scp only (e.g. -l)
    --ssh-extra-args=SSH_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to ssh only (e.g. -R)

  Privilege Escalation Options:
    control how and which user you become as on target hosts

    -b, --become        run operations with become (does not imply password
                        prompting)
    --become-method=BECOME_METHOD
                        privilege escalation method to use (default=sudo), use
                        `ansible-doc -t become -l` to list valid choices.
    --become-user=BECOME_USER
                        run operations as this user (default=root)
    -K, --ask-become-pass
                        ask for privilege escalation password
```

version:ansible 2.8.0

Comment: If I get this correctly you want to pass variable file run time you can use `include_vars` option for passing files at run time during command. There is also template module available that replaces the variables from an inventory file using the `{{ }}` syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can't package playbooks as zip or tgz files.  One option would be to use ansible-pull.  It checks a repository out and runs a specified playbook:  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-pull.html